# aspnet core appsettings.json loading

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, appsettings

I have ASP.NET Core (2.1) project that has `appsettings.json`. I use `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()`. The `appsettings.json` file has following configuration in File Properties:

Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

After build the `appsettings.json` ends up in `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyProj.runtimeconfig.json`.
The ASP.NET Core runtime loads it fine.

I created WebJobs (for .Net Core 2.1) and wanted to do the same - set Build Action to Content and let it loaded. In the `Main()` of Program.cs I have code like

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
  ...
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
{
    var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

    b.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    b.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);
    b.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", true, true);
    b.AddEnvironmentVariables();

    // Adding command line as a configuration source
    if (args != null)
    {
        b.AddCommandLine(args);
    }
}
```

But the runtime tries to load `appsettings.json` (instead of `MyWebJobProj.runtimeconfig.json`). So I had to set Build Action to None and Copy to Output Directory to Always.
However I would prefer the same approach like in ASP.NET Core - it handles somehow the file name transformation. Although in `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` is basically the same code like I have in my WebJob. What does the magic file name transformation in the configuration and why it works only in one type of project?

Answer (score 1):

The file `[ProjName].runtimeconfig.json` has a completely different meaning than `appsettings.json`. Ensure that `appsettings.json` was copied to output (set 'Copy to output' to 'always' or 'newer').